# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19:test

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

Build is failed when executing a test

this is the content of pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>localweb</groupId>
  <artifactId>localweb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
            <skip>false</skip>
                <suiteXMLFiles>
                    <suiteXMLFile>testng.xml</suiteXMLFile>
                </suiteXMLFiles>
            </configuration>
                        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
  <dependencies>            
    <dependency>              
         <groupId>junit</groupId>                               
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>                             
         <version>3.8.1</version>                               
         <scope>test</scope>                                
    </dependency>             
    <dependency>              
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>                              
        <version>2.45.0</version>                               
    </dependency>             
    <dependency>              
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
        <version>6.8</version>                              
        <scope>test</scope>                                     
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

this is the Root POM /home/user/workspace/localweb/pom.xml

When I execute this project in eclipse with 'Run as Maven Build' then the Build is successful. Only when executed through Jenkins the Build is failed.

Comment: Could you post the stracktrace you are having when launching the build on Jenkins?

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project mvnj: Error creating properties files for forking; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Permission denied -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionExcept

Comment: Error is clear: "Permission denied".

Comment: What should I do for fixing it?

Comment: After enabling strace received the following
**Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
 at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
 at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SystemPropertyManager.writePropertiesFile(SystemPropertyManager.java:76)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.BooterSerializer.serialize(BooterSerializer.java:126)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:226)
 ... 37 more**

Comment: @Testadmin Did you found any solution for this issue? If yes, please post the answer it will helpful for others

Comment: @Manigandan No I didn't find any solution for it until now.. And also it's been very long time I worked on this.